# Python threads and GIL

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

Let's say I have a thread and the main part of the program. Because of GIL, one thread should work at a time right (and not simulatenously)? But what if One of the threads is an infinite loop (or both for that matter)?

Would these two processes run in parallel?

```
def test():
    while True:
       print "hello"

def test2():
    while True:
       print "hi"

def start_thread():
    try: 
        thread.start_new_thread( test2,() )
    except:
        print "Error: Unable to start thread"
start_thread()
test()
```

Answer (score 6):

They'll run concurrently, but not actually in *parallel*. The OS will frequently switch back and forth between the two threads, so that they'll both be able to get their work done. This is what is meant by "concurrent"; one thread doesn't need to wait for the other to finish before it can start working. But because of the GIL, they'll never both actually be running at the exact same time, where each is being run on a different core in parallel. Each thread will run for a bit, pause while the other thread runs, then start running again, then pause, etc.

This is easy enough to see if you just run your example code. Here's the output on my machine:

```
hello
hi
hello
hi
hello
hi
hello
hi
hello
hi
hello
hi
hello
hi
hello
hi
hello
hi
```

Clearly, both threads are running. Each thread is just running slower than it would be if only one thread was running in the program.

Consider this example, where each thread calculates the fibonacci sequence:

```
import thread
import time


def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n

    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

def test():
    while True:
       start = time.time()
       out = fib(32)
       print "hello %s: %s" % (out, str(time.time() - start))

def test2():
    while True:
       out = fib(20)

def start_thread():
    try: 
        thread.start_new_thread( test2,() )
    except:
        print "Error: Unable to start thread"
#start_thread()
test()
```

With just `test` running (so no second thread), I get this output:

```
hello 2178309: 0.953778982162
hello 2178309: 0.954975128174
hello 2178309: 0.95578789711
hello 2178309: 0.949182033539
```

If I start up `test2` in the background as well, I get this:

```
hello 2178309: 4.07990288734
hello 2178309: 4.08523893356
hello 2178309: 2.51651597023
hello 2178309: 2.13291287422
hello 2178309: 2.19885015488
```

As you can see, performance takes a huge hit.

Note that if one of the threads is doing something that releases the GIL - like blocking I/O, or calling into a C library that releases the GIL - you won't see this kind of performance degradation, because in that case both threads actually can run in parallel. This doesn't apply in the above example, since neither thread is doing work that releases the GIL.

Comment: I see... Thanks. How much slower will it run? Is this critical? Let's say I am running a program for the stock market, one thread is receiving data from the broker and the other thread is executing orders. The latency should be as low as possible (milliseconds at the most). Would this still work?

Comment: @LuisCruz It depends somewhat on each thread is doing. In two threaded program, where one is mostly blocking on I/O and the other is doing calculations, it shouldn't be *horrible* but there will be some penalty whenever a request  comes in. Usually in Python you would spawn a background process using `multiprocessing` to handle the calculations, as long as the IPC overhead doesn't outweigh the benefit of avoiding the GIL. But if you want multiple threads doing calculations, you should absolutely be using processes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. On my case one thread is reading a named pipe, so if there's no data it gets blocked. The other thread is receiving data from the broker via a websocket API. So in my case threads shouldn't be too bad I suppose.

Comment: @LuisCruz It's usually pretty easy to switch between threads and processes, so you should be able to test each approach and see how performance is effected.

Comment: This is the best description of the threads and gil issue I've ever seen.